# Different behaviour of java spring boot application in intellij run and terminal

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application build in maven and open it in intellij when I run the main class then it will run successfully and receive the API responses as expected. But when I run same application in the terminal using `mvn spring-boot:run` then application run successfully but the responses of the api is different then expected.

expected responses:-
`{"result":{"balance":1970700,"currency":"DIVI"},"status":"true"}`

response that I'm getting is:-
`{"result":"getAccountState failed","status":"false"}`

This is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.diem</groupId>
    <artifactId>wallet</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>wallet</name>
    <description>Project for diem wallet</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dev.jlibra</groupId>
            <artifactId>jlibra-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dev.jlibra</groupId>
            <artifactId>jlibra-poller</artifactId>
            <version>0.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

`jlibra-core` dependency that I'm adding manually in application in the libraries

Why this is happening any suggestions?

Comment: Because it is wednesday? Sorry but without seeing code, configuration etc. this will just be impossible to answer.

Comment: File > Invalidate caches and reboot IntelliJ. If it doesn't work, `mvn clean install`.

Comment: @M.Deinum please check the edit

Comment: @gantoin please check this edit

Comment: We don't how your application works only with the `pom.xml`; I think that your IntelliJ "Run configuration" is pretty different than an `mvn spring-boot:run`.
(Maybe a database connection issue?)

Comment: no there is no db connection in my application

Comment: My application is just connecting to a blockchain and getting the results

Comment: Just dumping dependencies without seeing **what you are doing in code** will not help your chances to an answer. So please include the code you are running. Also stop mixing different versions of jars (you are ,mixing 2.4.3 and 2.4.5 from Spring BOot resulting in different Spring versions which can lead to issues. ).